# How to calculte mosfet capacitors (Cgs Cds Cdg) knowing the charges Q

Tags: mosfet, capacitance, parasitic-capacitance

I need to use the best model for the MOSFET in my circuit I'm simulation on PSIM, the MOSFET is Si4108-TI-GE3.

But I am not given the parasitic capacitance values (Cgs Cds Cdg), I am only given this:

[image: dynamic charge characteristics of the capacitor to be modeled]

I think I should use Q=CU, but I don't see how to use Q=CU for Cds since I only have Total gate charge and I don't know if that is the drain-source charge. How do I calculate the necessary parasitic capacitance values?

Comment: Generally, `Q=CV`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the data sheet: -

[image]

Ciss is gate-source capacitance. You should be able to work out the other two.

Comment: reading the datasheet doesn't help if you don't know what you're looking for!  I assume that is why the OP asked the question.

Comment: @jrive so, you think on that basis (your opinion) it's OK to downvote my answer then? Did you notice that the op accepted this answer and therefore your concerns are somewhat badly displaced from the OP's.

Comment: yes….I find those types of answers discouraging to people who are seeking help.  Apologies if misinterpreted your intent.

Answer (score 10):

I realize that I am very late to the party but the question remains unanswered.

*Cgd = Crss*

*Cgs = Ciss - Crss*

*Cds = Coss - Crss*

You'll need to pick the values at the operating conditions you are working at.

This video should give some ideas https://youtu.be/iATO3mUKBPc

Answer (score 4):

The capacitances vary significantly with voltage so it's not so easy. (A different MOSFET)

[image]

Here is a [SPICE model](http://www.vishay.com/docs/68138/si4108dy.pdf) for the si4108:

[image]