# Bandwidth of voltage divider with PMOS switch

Tags: bandwidth, pmos

Planning to measure (varying under switching e-bike load) voltage from a battery.

To step down the voltage panning to use a voltage divider and buffer the output to an ADC via an op-amp.

To completely switch off the device when the e-bike controller is off will need to switch off the current through the voltage divider (maybe this is an overkill considering how small the current is (~2mA), the controller's quiescent current is probably greater).

Planning to switch the divider with a PMOS.

How do I calculate the bandwidth of the divider + PMOS?

I suppose I should use Rds_on of the PMOS and Cin and Cout of the PMOS to get an equivalent circuit?

I first thought I would represent the PMOS as Rds_on in parallel with Cgs but I'm looking at PMOS datasheets and they only give Cin and Cout.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr4xHx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why not use \$950k:50k//0.1uF\$ and forget the switch

Comment: Would it be more susceptible to EMI with higher resistor values(lower current) and more error due to the op-amp's finite input impedance?

Comment: The 0.1uF//50k=5ms so as long as wire loop area is minimized with twisted pairs or STP cable, spikes are attenuated so choose T=RC to exceed your  ADC conversion time.

Comment: Show us the PMOS datasheet.

Comment: I've not selected a particular one yet, bug e.g. this one https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Unisonic-Tech-UT2955G-AA3-R_C127043.pdf

Comment: Check the \$\mathrm{V_{GS}}\$ rating of the PMOS -- most of 'em are only good to 20V.

Comment: @TimWescott, thanks for the comment! I suppose I will need to add a driving circuit for the gate or use a different type of transistor for the switching, 60V gate/source PMOS transistors seem to be non-existent.

Comment: @axk if you're not switching it too fast, you can just use a resistive divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image should help you place the capacitances where they belong in the MOSFET model. You need all three and they should all be listed in the datasheet.

Personally though, I probably wouldn't bother with the MOSFET parasitic capacitances in this case.

[image]

https://micro.rohm.com/en/techweb/knowledge/si/s-si/03-s-si/4873
https://micro.rohm.com/en/techweb/upload/2017/03/si_2-2_capf.gif

Comment: I saw this article. Need to figure out what would the equivalent capacitance be in this case expressed via Ciss and Coss that are given in the datasheet.

Comment: You need Crss too. which is also given in the datasheet. Note that they are given under a specific set of test conditions.

Comment: I've also found this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/244894/69374 which follows from the above model I suppose